# Text not display proper in wrap panel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate, stackpanel, wrappanel

```
<WrapPanel Margin="20,5,10,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EvenNotesItemsTemplate}" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  />
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OddNotesItemsTemplate}" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding }"  />

</WrapPanel>


<DataTemplate x:Key="OddNotesItemsTemplate">
 <WrapPanel x:Name="OddNotesStackPanel"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Superscript}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="8"/>
  <TextBlock Text=" "/>
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"   Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal"/>
</WrapPanel>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="OddNotesStackPanel" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </Trigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
 </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="EvenNotesItemsTemplate">
<WrapPanel x:Name="EvenNotesStackPanel"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Superscript}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="8"/>
<TextBlock Text=" "/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal"/>
</WrapPanel>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
 <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="EvenNotesStackPanel" Value="Collapsed"/>
 </Trigger>
 </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

It shows data

> 1 Files should be added not deleted.
>   2 Files should not delete.It is
>   very secure data.It is very secure data.It is very secure data.It is
>   very secure data.

Actually it wrap the 2nd point to next line.But I want start 2nd point start from first line end and if it will be long move to next line the remain text.

But I want my data like...

> 1 Files should be added not deleted.2 Files should not delete.It is
>   very secure data.It is very secure data.It is very secure data.It is
>   very secure data.

Please help me how is it possible.